# Calculating 10% rebate on sales value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to work out a 10% rebate value for the sales value, not sure how to do this. I'm new to SQL, Thanks for any help.

```
select customer_code, invoice_date, sales_order_number, product_code, 
    qty_inv, sales_value, b.mpn
from sales_summary as a
    INNER JOIN stock_summary as b ON a.product_code = b.part
where invoice_date > date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '3 months'
    and customer_code in ('SSMIDC3','SSMIDC2','SBERDC2','STWYB','SSMIDCE')
```

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT sales_value * 0.9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
select customer_code, invoice_date, sales_order_number, product_code,
       qty_inv, sales_value, b.mpn,
       (0.1 * sales_value) as rebate_value
. . .
```